# Getting rid of NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE?

Tags: java, guava, findbugs

I'm getting `NP_NULL_ON_SOME_PATH_FROM_RETURN_VALUE` in this snippet

```
final Integer id = Ints.tryParse(idString);
FailReason.NO_SUCH_THING.checkCondition(id!=null);
something.setId(id.intValue());
```

Here, `checkCondition` works just like [Preconditions.checkArgument](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkArgument%28boolean%29) except for it throws my own exception. Throwing NPE or IAE is not appropriate here, as it's checking an external input rather than a programming error.

FindBugs complains that *"The return value from a method is dereferenced without a null check, and the return value of that method is one that should generally be checked for null. This may lead to a NullPointerException when the code is executed.*"

Can I teach FindBugs that `checkCondition` never returns normally when the argument is `false`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I (sort of) solved it by adding

```
assert id!=null;
```

It's redundant and ugly, but still less ugly than `@SuppressFBWarnings` and more local.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [java.util.Objects.requireNonNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull%28T%29) to please FindBugs:

```
final Integer id = Ints.tryParse(idString);
FailReason.NO_SUCH_THING.checkCondition(id!=null);
something.setId(Objects.requireNonNull(id).intValue());
```

Or you might be able to use [java.util.Objects.isNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#isNull-java.lang.Object-) to fool FindBugs.

```
final Integer id = Ints.tryParse(idString);
FailReason.NO_SUCH_THING.checkCondition(!Objects.isNull(id));
something.setId(id.intValue());
```

Comment: I can't... it's Java 8 and (I forgot to say) I'm using 7.

Comment: You could use the Guava equivalent. Since you know it's not null at that point, this is merely to satisfy FindBugs. I'd probably prefer the assertion which gets compiled out in production.

Comment: Objects.requireNonNull does not appease Spotbugs: https://github.com/spotbugs/spotbugs/issues/651